# How can I access a binary framework in the GitHub Release with SPM when the repo is private?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

How can I access a binary framework in the GitHub Release with SPM when the repo is private?

If I access my framework from a public repo then this works:

```
        .binaryTarget(
            name: “Xxxxxxx”,
            url: "https://nexusxxxxx/nexus/content/repositories/xxxxx/multiplatformxc-release/1.2.3/multiplatformxc-release-1.2.3.zip",
            checksum: checksum
        )
```

But I want to access the same file from my github repo, which is private.
The file is generated and saved the GitHub Release section.

So, the URL is something like:

```
https://github.com/xxxxx-uk/xxxxx-multiplatform/releases/download/v1.2.3/xxxxxx-multiplatform.xcframework.zip
```

Evidently, if I use something like:

```
        .binaryTarget(
            name: “Xxxxxxx”,
            url: "https://github.com/xxxxx-uk/xxxxx-multiplatform/releases/download/v1.2.3/xxxxxx-multiplatform.xcframework.zip",
            checksum: checksum
        )
```

is going to fail because it is private, in fact, this is the error message I see from SPM:

```
artifact of binary target ‘Xxxxxxx’ failed download: invalid status code 404
```

(that is, unauthorized)

Is it possible that somehow we can use SSH authentication?
(I am already using that for .package and it is working great)

If I use something like:

```
        .binaryTarget(
            name: “Xxxxxxx”,
            url: "git@github.com:xxxxx-uk/xxxxx-multiplatform/releases/download/v1.2.3/xxxxxx-multiplatform.xcframework.zip",
            checksum: checksum
        )
```

is failing with this error:

```
invalid URL scheme for binary target ‘Xxxxxx; valid schemes are: https
```

(but as I said, it is working for packages)

So, is this technically possible? Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/pull/2833

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not technically possible as of Xcode 13.

Downloading *release assets* in a private GitHub repo requires making an authenticated request that SPM doesn't currently support.

For the relevant discussion, see:
https://forums.swift.org/t/spm-support-basic-auth-for-non-git-binary-dependency-hosts/37878/35